# Issues with pasting certain Excel charts as Link (Microsoft Excel Chart Object)

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a PPT in which I want to paste a chart from an excel as a link (Microsoft Excel Chart Object). I have been pasting many different charts from different Excel files into the same PPT file without any issues. However, when I try to paste a chart from one specific excel file into the PPT, the "Paste Link" option is greyed out and not available. I have posted various tables from this excel (including the source table of the chart that I am trying to paste) as a link into the powerpoint file already, so I do not understand why it does not work for these two specific charts.

I am thankful for any help!

Comment: How exactly are you doing the paste?